# Android Studio Error in app with real-time firebase store

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on a project and have connected the app with firebase, in connecting real-time database now I am getting this error
"Could not create task ':app:processReleaseGoogleServices'. DefaultTaskContainer#NamedDomainObjectProvider.configure(Action) on task set cannot be executed in the current context"
These are the 2 Gradle files:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'

}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.imrankhan.fitnessapp"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.3.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.0.1'
    implementation 'androidx.coordinatorlayout:coordinatorlayout:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:23.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:20.0.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

**<File two code>**


// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.3"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.9'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While using the firebase bom, you don't need to include the individual firebase dependency versions or else that would result in overlaps and throw errors.

Replace the dependencies section with:

```
 dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.3.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth'
    implementation 'androidx.coordinatorlayout:coordinatorlayout:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    }
```

Comment: dependencies { classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.3" classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.9' // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong // in the individual module build.gradle files }               
 It worked for me by changing this above code like this:                                   dependencies { classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.1" classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.8' }

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the dependency in build gradle 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.9' to 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.8' that's work for me.